How do I join my table containing primary key parts with my target table in PostgreSQL?
I have a table pk_map which has 3 cols:
result_id, pk_key, pk_value



result_id
pk_key
pk_value




101
client_a
2233


101
client_b
3311


102
client_a
3333


...





And I have another table target_table, which has composite primary key



col1
col2
client_a
col4
client_b




---
---
2233
---
3311


---
---
3333
---
11



I would like to write a sql, which joined these tables on primary key parts.
In the result, I gotta have target_table (the second one), which will contain all rows, corresponding to all pk_map records. In other words, the first table contains id`s for target_table results. Earlier I made some SELECT pk1, pk2 FROM target_table where smth = smth. And the first one contains results
Maybe this task is better to make in programming language. Please, reccomend me how to solve this
I think maybe over partition may help, but now I`m bad at it

Add a few more rows of sample table data, and also specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

I hope now it`s more clear

Can you also specify the expected result?

The second table in my post is literally what I expect. If I used SELECT, I would make sth like "SELECT * FROM target_table WHERE client_a IN ([lot of values]) AND  client_b IN ([lot of values]);

try this
with client_a as (
select * from 
pk_map where pk_key = 'client_a'
)
, client_b as (
select * from 
pk_map where pk_key = 'client_b'
)
select * from 
target_table t 
    left join client_a a on a.pk_value = t.client_a
    left join client_b b on b.pk_value = t.client_b


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
